# Вычисление процентов на проценты

Tags: алгоритм, математика, формулы

Добрый день!
У меня второй раз в жизни возникает задачка по вычислению процентов на проценты (сумбурно, но сейчас постараюсь объяснить на примере).

Итак, у нас есть сумма, допустим 100 рублей. Эту сумму нужно заплатить человеку через ИП, ИП не хочет терять на налогах и хочет получить такую сумму в которую были бы включены налоги, а для налоговой нужно получить свои 6% от суммы поступившей на счет.

Получается нам нужно зачислить на счет ИП такую сумму которая бы включала налог на саму сумму и налог на проценты (6%).

Умнее чем цикл я пока не придумал, т.е. схематично получается так:

```
double amount, precision, tax, taxes;

amount = 100.00; //сумма платежа
precision = 0.01; //нужная точность, в данном случае до второго знака после запятой
tax = amount; //для удобства изначальный налог устанавливаем равным сумме (см формулу расчета процента в цикле)
taxes = 0.00; //итоговая сумма налога (вместе с нужными процентами)

do {
    tax = tax * 0.06; //или tax = (tax / 100) * 6;
    taxes += tax;
} while (tax >= precision)

System.out.format("Ваша сумма: %f.%n и налог на нее: %f.%n", amount, taxes);
```

В итоге мы получим в taxes сумму процентов, которую будет необходимо заплатить в налоговую и после уплаты этой суммы у нас на счету останется 100 рублей.

**ВОПРОС:** как называется такой тип расчета? Есть ли какая нибудь математическая формула для этого? Так как мне кажется через цикл решать это совсем не удобно.

Comment: x (100 руб). -  это 106% (100%+6%=106%) ||| x/106*100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не всегда стоит решать задачу кодом.
Это обычное уравнение школьного уровня.

Обозначаете всю сумму как x.
Налогов с нее придется заплатить 6/100 * x

После вычета налогов должно остаться 1000:

```
x - (6 / 100) * x = 1000
x * (1 - 6 / 100) = 1000
x * 94 / 100 = 1000
x = 1000 * 100 / 94
x = 1063.83
```

В общем виде:

```
amount = target * 100 / (100 - tax)
```